# UIButton custom retina image stretched in iPad Retina Display

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

I have one issue with iPad retina image. When i was executing my add in normal ipad it looks great.

But when I am executing this app in iPad Retina then `UIButton` custom images is stretched upwards.

Also I added images for "@2x" icon images for retina mode.

Using this code:

```
UIButton *btnEye=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5.5, 35, 35)];
[btnEye setImage:eyeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[reportToolbar addSubview:btnEye];
```

**In Normal Mode :**

[image]

**In Reitna Mode:**

[image]

Comment: How do you create eyeImage?

Comment: It's not a good idea to create origin of the button like this "CGRectMake(10, 5.5, 35, 35)". In non-retina device your button and the text will be blurry, because of the 5.5.

Comment: UIImage *eyeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye.png"];

Comment: Hey Dave, I tried with UIbutton cutomtype also but it give same result :(

Comment: Whats the size of the retina image??

Comment: check the size of the retina image

Comment: retina image size is 44 x 44 and normal image size is 22 x 22

Comment: Four upvotes for this question? Hmmm.

Comment: Clear your project and recompile it. I'm very sure this is caused by the retina size image, not being the exact duplicate of the normal one.

Comment: Hi Lefteris, I sort issue that i need to apply @2x.png images manually, But still i am getting this images in zoomed format not like  normal display.

Comment: I edited this and added current retina display issue. Please if you have any solution for this let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried without .png extension . `UIImage *eyeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye"];`

Comment: Is the @2x image really in the project? Can you make an ipa and look into it?

Comment: Can you open your @2x with photshop?, maybe it is corrupt. Something like that happend to me, just no with an image, but the app act like the file just "dont exist", without error and nothing else. Other option is the size, you say your image es 22x22 and your button is 35 x 35, tray forcing the "aspect fit"

Answer (score 1):

Are the retina images really having double resolution than normal or it has the same resolution as the normal one?

Answer (score 0):

simply , you should replace the "@2x" images with the normal ones , it seems, the images' sizes are reversed .

Answer (score -2):

This code would not win the beauty contest but you could give it a try!

Add a function to your class to recognise if you have a retina device

```
- (BOOL)isRetina {
   return [self respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && (self.scale == 2.0);
}
```

And when you set the eyeImage do this

```
UIImageView *eyeImage = nil;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && [self isRetina]) {
    eyeImage = [UIImageView imageNamed:@"eye@2x.png"];
} else {
    eyeImage = [UIImageView imageNamed:@"eye.png"];
}
```

This way you force your device to use the retina image if it has one :-).

Comment: Isn't there already something in XCode preferences that does exactly that? Can you imagine having to specify a separate version for every device with a Retina display as well as having to list all images? No way!